# how to get feature map for a given kernel function

Tags: machine-learning, svm, kernel-trick, libsvm

With respect to support vector machine, there are multiple types of kernels, such as `The Gaussian Kernel`, `The homogeneous kernel`, `The linear kernel`,etc. Are there any ways to calculate the exact formula of feature map for a given kernel function?